# How can i invoke a method of an object to display some properties of that object in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to understand how to leverage the power of a method on an object.  It's easy enough to render the properties of my object as long as they are key/value pairs.  But when the property is a method, I don't understand how to invoke that method.

If I split up my what I am trying to accomplish, it breaks out like this:

```
function displayPropertiesOfMangoFruit() { } ... displayPropertiesOfMangoFruit()
```

My function accomplishes printing out the property of my object and inserting into my div.
http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/7hHAR/1/

But when I try to print out the property of my object by making that function a method of it, I have no luck.
http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/XH3ML/2/

Can someone explain to me how I can execute a method on my object that will print out some simple html that includes the properties of my object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call it:

```
mangoFruit.showName();
```

Comment: Hi, Scott, you make me realize I was asking the wrong question. But it lead me to the right answer. Thanks much! (It's not working in JS fiddle, but it does work in all browsers.) Here's a link to a fiddle w/ your solution applied.  http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/XH3ML/4/

Comment: You have to spell it right for it to work :)  (Remember, capitalization counts!)